# Add specific text into a specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How do I copy and paste a value in cell A2 into the cell specified in cell A1. For example A1 contains F3. And A2 contains 2. I want to write "2" into cell F3

Comment: I just want to know how to go to a cell. I dont want you to write the full script, i just want to know how to go to a certain cell based on a specific text in another cell.

Comment: Instead of Copy & Paste,  write `=A2 ` in Cell `F3`, so whenever value changes in `A2` Excel reflect in `F3`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with the code below:

```
Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
```

### Explanation

- `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value` will get the text in `A1`, therefore: `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value).Value` gets the text in whatever cell is referenced in `A1`.
- `Sheet1.Range("A2").Value` will get the text in `A2`.
- Since `.Value` is settable, we're setting the value of the referenced cell to the text in `A2`.

Comment: explains how to write a value in a cell. If you want to go to a cell, try `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value).Activate`.